# How to find to good line css for background-image and line-gradient with Safari?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I've a problem with "background-image" and "linear-gradient" between Chrome and Safari (on iPhone too).

The result that I want is the same than I've on Chrome:

[image: Background-image with Chrome]

And this is the result I've with Safari on my Mac or with my iPhone:

[image: Background-image with Safari]

This is my css :

```
<div class="container-fluid container-bg-details-game" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0.00), #081B33), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0.00), #081B33),
url({{ asset('build/static/Cubes-Abstract-Wallpaper.jpg')}}); background-position: center right;background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; padding: 0; height: 600px">
```

I've try with the extension -webkit- but nothing changes on Safari.

If someone have an idea ?

Comment: Can you post correct code for HTML and CSS?

Comment: @Manjuboyz My code is just above. I haven’t put in a different css file because I need to access my image with a variable.